# Meteor Collection to ChartJs Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, charts

I have a Meteor Collection which I want to be presented into a graph using ChartJS. I was able to follow how ChartJS documentation.

My problem now is how to transform my collection and pass it on to ChartJS.

ChartJs Data format :

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }]
};
```

This is how my collection was saved :

```
Categories.insert({
    categoryname : $('#categoryname').val(),
    value : $('#categoryvalue').val()
});
```

I wanted to use the categoryname as the chart labels and the value as the  data. How am I going to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it work after another try after I posted my question.

```
function drawChart() {
    var cur = Categories.find();

    collData = [];
    cur.forEach(function(cat){
        collData.push([cat.value]);
    });

    collLabel = [];
    cur.forEach(function(cat){
        collLabel.push([cat.categoryname]);
    });

    var data = {
        labels: collLabel,
        datasets: [{
            data: collData
        }]
    };
};
```

I am not sure if this the right way to do it but it works for now.